# How to group digits?

Tags: c++, string

I need a function which get a string from a double value in format `xx'xxx'xxx.xxxx'.

The function must work fast.

How can I write it?

Comment: If the desired format is part of some particular locale, then you can set that locale and use stream extraction. Otherwise you'll have to roll your own function.

Comment: _"I need a function.."_ What do you think StackOverflow.com is all about ?

Comment: If the format `xx'xxx'xxx.xxxx' means that value 12345678.0123 is expressed as 12'345'678.0123, remove all "'" then use build-in function "stod()". In many case, build-in function has good performance.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the double to a string, look into either

atof http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

or

to_string http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

Once you have your string, there are several options to choose, but all of them find the decimal point and either insert ' after groups of three, or construct a new string by copying over the original string, but also adding ' after copying each group of three.

Assuming you are using a std::string, something like this should work just fine:

```
const int GROUP_LENGTH = 3;
auto stringLength = s.length();
auto insertPosition = s.find(".");
if (insertPosition == string::npos) { // no decimal part
    insertPosition = stringLength;
}
while (insertPosition > 0) {
    insertPosition -= GROUP_LENGTH;
    s.insert(insertPosition, '\'');
}
```

Also, never mind the intellectual elitists. Many of these people were born doing headstands.

Comment: Thank you. I understand all you wrote. But will this algorithm work fast?

Comment: Why is fast so important to you in this case? The general rule is to write first and optimize later. Most things are plenty fast in the first place, especially on modern computers, so it's a waste to optimize prematurely. Don't just get stuck in the "everything as fast as possible" mindset.

Comment: When data in my application is updating this function is called many times.

Comment: The best approach in ~all circumstances~ is to time your execution for run time, compare that time to specs/needs, and only ~then~ if it's not acceptable, then optimize. But fears ahead of time is not useful, and never ever guess if it's optimal -- always always time it. You can't always tell how fast something will run by looks.

Comment: @Ufx: A professional engineer does not guess but measure. Execution speed has many factors, and "fast" and "slow" are extremely subjective attributes. Asking whether this algorithm is "fast" is as meaningless a question as "Is this train fast?". Besides, I think you expect the wrong things from SO. People here do not provide a paid service; you have to actively cooperate and try things yourself.